# How can I display cloud storage hosted images in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, looker-studio

I wish to produce a Data Studio report with a grid of images and their metadata. These images are stored on a Google Cloud Storage bucket. This bucket must be secure ie not open to allusers.

Is there any way to hook this bucket into Data Studio?

The Google Cloud Storage Connector only seems to allow me to access csv files from there, and the Image control requires a URL which I do not know how to get from the bucket and surely won't pass the security anyway.

I  have a secure Cloud MySQL DB and that works in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7511998), the Google Cloud Storage connector can only handle files of tabular data in CSV format. This means that it does not support what you are intending to do. As for the URL, you must use the [IMAGE function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7570489?hl=en#), but the permissions must be set to allUsers, so unfortunately, this would not help you either.

I would advise to ask in the [official community help forum](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/new?hl=en) to see if anyone might have a workaround for your use case.